# How to let users allow other users to view specific node content?

Tags: nodes

I'm using Drupal 9

I would like users to be able to allow other users to view their node content. Ideally a user will request access to view the content and the content owner will grant them view access.
How would I go about that?

I've looked at [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess), but it doesn't seem ready for Drupal 9 yet.
[Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) has nothing close for Drupal 9

Comment: Welp, use D8 then.

Comment: Will D8 allow me to do what I want?

Comment: [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) is available for D8, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a small custom module.

1. Make a allowed users/node list (database table oe entity)
2. Implement hook_entity_access()
3. return AccessResult::allowed() or AccessResult::forbidden() according to your user/node table

Comment: I am considering creating a module just for this. Do you have a suggestion for how to create the request to view a node?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you could maybe use also the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.
It permits you to create groups of  entities, that can be visible only by the user roles that has access to a certain group. Also, the roles in groups can be different from the Drupal Roles.
So, for each group you can create a moderator role, that can decide the visible content for each one of the other roles of the group.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a suggestion about how to create the request to view a node? Or does Group module do that?

Comment: You can create a new group and after go to tab 'Nodes' and add the entities you want to be accessible for that group.

Comment: That sounds like a viable option. Thanks!